Movie about a post apocalyptic world with a scorching hot sun

I remember there being a lot of robots cause they can survive in the heat, there was def a robot dog
Humans die if they go out in the heat too long
I think MC dies but not sure, a tennis ball is possibly thrown near the end of the movie
There's a trailer involved (the vehicle) and a robot guy
movie ends with the golden gate bridge possibly
Robot guy screws something up near the end of the movie at a gas station (???) which somehow leads to MC death


This is Finch (2021).

The story follows an aging man named Finch, a survivor in a now nearly uninhabitable Earth, who builds and teaches a robot to take care of his dog when he dies.
...
Fifteen years have passed since a massive solar flare destroyed the ozone layer, turning the planet Earth into a largely uninhabitable wasteland ravaged by extreme weather events while being scorched by the sun's ultraviolet rays, increasing surface temperatures to 150 °F (66 °C; 339 K). One of the few survivors, robotics engineer Finch Weinberg, lives alone with his dog Goodyear and a helper-robot Dewey in an underground St. Louis laboratory once owned by the company he worked for before the cataclysm. Finch only ventures outside, wearing a protective suit, to search for supplies.




The movie does indeed end at the Golden Gate Bridge in San Francisco.
